# Populate html table with results from dropdown list using SQL, Javascript, and/or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sql, drop-down-menu

I've been searching for relevant answers for the last two days but haven't been able to make anything of the answers.

I am creating a webpage using javascript, PHP and SQL that will eventually be more robust than what I'm asking but for the time being this is my problem.

I have an initial dropdown list that is populated with the names of 39 distinct tables (constellations or groups of satellites) in a SQL database. Based on the first SQL query, on submit, the page displays the entire table as html on the bottom of the page.

Additionally, a second query populates a second dropdown list (specific satellites/objects within the constellation) that shows the name of each line from the chosen table. The second dropdown list shows fine.

However, when I click submit after the second dropdown, the query should be passed to a html table to show only the chosen row information (orbital parameters for the satellite/object) from the second query. Instead, when I click submit, nothing shows in the table and the page refreshes to go back to its initial state. I don't know how to successfully pass the query to the table. Each table contains anywhere from 8 to 2700 distinct objects (for a total of more than 6000) so I can't simply list each row, especially since the data changes daily.

The data from the table will eventually be used to calculate orbits using java or another method and show them in the embedded google earth page.

I am familiar with javascript, php, and sql but am not really familiar with other methods but I am open to suggestions.

Below is the relevant code for the page.

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['constellation'])) {
    $constellation = $_POST['constellation']; }
    else {
    $constellation = 'Space Stations';
  }


  if (isset($_POST['satellite'])) {
    $satellite = $_POST['satellite']; }
    else {
    $satellite = 'ISS (Zarya)';
  }

?>

  <p>Use the pull-down menu's to choose the specific constellation (group) of satellites to view the most recent orbital data.</a></p>
  <hr />

  <div class="masterpulldown">

  <table class="pulldown">
  <tr>
    <td "colspan="2">
      <p class="pulldownheader">Constellation Query</p>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="pulldownGroup" name="pulldownGroup" method="post" >
      <select id="constellation" name="constellation" value=$constellation >
      <option value="Last 30 Days" <?php if($constellation=="Last 30 Days") echo "selected"; ?> >Last 30 Days</option>
      <option value="Space Stations" <?php if($constellation=="Space Stations") echo "selected"; ?> >Space Stations</option>
      <option value="100 (Or So) Brightest" <?php if($constellation=="100 (Or So) Brightest") echo "selected"; ?> >100 (Or So) Brightest</option>
      <option value="Weather" <?php if($constellation=="Weather") echo "selected"; ?> >Weather</option>
      <option value="Noaa" <?php if($constellation=="Noaa") echo "selected"; ?> >Noaa</option>
      <option value="Goes" <?php if($constellation=="Goes") echo "selected"; ?> >Goes</option>
      <option value="Earth Resources" <?php if($constellation=="Earth Resources") echo "selected"; ?> >Earth Resources</option>
      <option value="Search And Rescue (Sarsat)" <?php if($constellation=="Search And Rescue (Sarsat)") echo "selected"; ?> >Search And Rescue (Sarsat)</option>
      <option value="Disaster Monitoring" <?php if($constellation=="Disaster Monitoring") echo "selected"; ?> >Disaster Monitoring</option>
      <option value="Tracking And Data Relay Satellite System (Tdrss)" <?php if($constellation=="Tracking And Data Relay Satellite System (Tdrss)") echo "selected"; ?> >Tracking And Data Relay Satellite System (Tdrss)</option>
      <option value="Geostationary" <?php if($constellation=="Geostationary") echo "selected"; ?> >Geostationary</option>
      <option value="Intelsat" <?php if($constellation=="Intelsat") echo "selected"; ?> >Intelsat</option>
      <option value="Gorizont" <?php if($constellation=="Gorizont") echo "selected"; ?> >Gorizont</option>
      <option value="Raduga" <?php if($constellation=="Raduga") echo "selected"; ?> >Raduga</option>
      <option value="Molniya" <?php if($constellation=="Molniya") echo "selected"; ?> >Molniya</option>
      <option value="Iridium" <?php if($constellation=="Iridium") echo "selected"; ?> >Iridium</option>
      <option value="Orbcomm" <?php if($constellation=="Orbcomm") echo "selected"; ?> >Orbcomm</option>
      <option value="Globalstar" <?php if($constellation=="Globalstar") echo "selected"; ?> >Globalstar</option>
      <option value="Amateur Radio" <?php if($constellation=="Amateur Radio") echo "selected"; ?> >Amateur Radio</option>
      <option value="Experimental" <?php if($constellation=="Experimental") echo "selected"; ?> >Experimental</option>
      <option value="Communication Satellites - Other" <?php if($constellation=="Communication Satellites - Other") echo "selected"; ?> >Communication Satellites - Other</option>
      <option value="Gps Operational" <?php if($constellation=="Gps Operational") echo "selected"; ?> >Gps Operational</option>
      <option value="Glonass Operational" <?php if($constellation=="Glonass Operational") echo "selected"; ?> >Glonass Operational</option>
      <option value="Galileo" <?php if($constellation=="Galileo") echo "selected"; ?> >Galileo</option>
      <option value="Satellite-Based Augmentation System" <?php if($constellation=="Satellite-Based Augmentation System") echo "selected"; ?> >Satellite-Based Augmentation System</option>
      <option value="Navy Navigation Satellite System (Nnss)" <?php if($constellation=="Navy Navigation Satellite System (Nnss)") echo "selected"; ?> >Navy Navigation Satellite System (Nnss)</option>
      <option value="Russian Leo Navigation" <?php if($constellation=="Russian Leo Navigation") echo "selected"; ?> >Russian Leo Navigation</option>
      <option value="Space And Earth Science" <?php if($constellation=="Space And Earth Science") echo "selected"; ?> >Space And Earth Science</option>
      <option value="Geodetic" <?php if($constellation=="Geodetic") echo "selected"; ?> >Geodetic</option>
      <option value="Engineering" <?php if($constellation=="Engineering") echo "selected"; ?> >Engineering</option>
      <option value="Education" <?php if($constellation=="Education") echo "selected"; ?> >Education</option>
      <option value="Miscellaneous Military" <?php if($constellation=="Miscellaneous Military") echo "selected"; ?> >Miscellaneous Military</option>
      <option value="Radar Calibration" <?php if($constellation=="Radar Calibration") echo "selected"; ?> >Radar Calibration</option>
      <option value="Cubesats" <?php if($constellation=="Cubesats") echo "selected"; ?> >Cubesats</option>
      <option value="Miscellaneous Satellites - Other" <?php if($constellation=="Miscellaneous Satellites - Other") echo "selected"; ?> >Miscellaneous Satellites - Other</option>
      <option value="Fengyun 1C Debris" <?php if($constellation=="Fengyun 1C Debris") echo "selected"; ?> >Fengyun 1C Debris</option>
      <option value="Iridium 33 Debris" <?php if($constellation=="Iridium 33 Debris") echo "selected"; ?> >Iridium 33 Debris</option>
      <option value="Cosmos 2251 Debris" <?php if($constellation=="Cosmos 2251 Debris") echo "selected"; ?> >Cosmos 2251 Debris</option>
      <option value="Breeze-M Breakup" <?php if($constellation=="Breeze-M Breakup") echo "selected"; ?> >Breeze-M Breakup</option>
      <input id="submit" type=submit value=submit />
      </form>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>


<?php

  require_once('connectvars.php');
  // require_once('appvars.php');


  // Connect to the database 
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  $a1=array("Last30Days","SpaceStations","HundredOrSoBrightest","Weather","Noaa","Goes","EarthResources","SearchAndRescueSarsat","DisasterMonitoring","TrackingAndDataRelaySatelliteSystemTdrss","Geostationary","Intelsat","Gorizont","Raduga","Molniya","Iridium","Orbcomm","Globalstar","AmateurRadio","Experimental","CommunicationSatellitesOther","GpsOperational","GlonassOperational","Galileo","SatelliteBasedAugmentationSystem","NavyNavigationSatelliteSystemNnss","RussianLeoNavigation","SpaceAndEarthScience","Geodetic","Engineering","Education","MiscellaneousMilitary","RadarCalibration","Cubesats","MiscellaneousSatellitesOther","Fengyun1CDebris","Iridium33Debris","Cosmos2251Debris","BreezeMRBBreakup");
  $a2=array("Last 30 Days","Space Stations","100 (Or So) Brightest","Weather","Noaa","Goes","Earth Resources","Search And Rescue (Sarsat)","Disaster Monitoring","Tracking And Data Relay Satellite System (Tdrss)","Geostationary","Intelsat","Gorizont","Raduga","Molniya","Iridium","Orbcomm","Globalstar","Amateur Radio","Experimental","Communication Satellites - Other","Gps Operational","Glonass Operational","Galileo","Satellite-Based Augmentation System","Navy Navigation Satellite System (Nnss)","Russian Leo Navigation","Space And Earth Science","Geodetic","Engineering","Education","Miscellaneous Military","Radar Calibration","Cubesats","Miscellaneous Satellites - Other","Fengyun 1C Debris","Iridium 33 Debris","Cosmos 2251 Debris","Breeze-M Breakup");
  $arr=array_combine($a1, $a2);

      $Last30Days = $arr["Last30Days"];
      $SpaceStations = $arr["SpaceStations"];
      $HundredOrSoBrightest = $arr["HundredOrSoBrightest"];
      $Weather = $arr["Weather"];
      $Noaa = $arr["Noaa"];
      $Goes = $arr["Goes"];
      $EarthResources = $arr["EarthResources"];
      $SearchAndRescueSarsat = $arr["SearchAndRescueSarsat"];
      $DisasterMonitoring = $arr["DisasterMonitoring"];
      $TrackingAndDataRelaySatelliteSystemTdrss = $arr["TrackingAndDataRelaySatelliteSystemTdrss"];
      $Geostationary = $arr["Geostationary"];
      $Intelsat = $arr["Intelsat"];
      $Gorizont = $arr["Gorizont"];
      $Raduga = $arr["Raduga"];
      $Molniya = $arr["Molniya"];
      $Iridium = $arr["Iridium"];
      $Orbcomm = $arr["Orbcomm"];
      $Globalstar = $arr["Globalstar"];
      $AmateurRadio = $arr["AmateurRadio"];
      $Experimental = $arr["Experimental"];
      $CommunicationSatellitesOther = $arr["CommunicationSatellitesOther"];
      $GpsOperational = $arr["GpsOperational"];
      $GlonassOperational = $arr["GlonassOperational"];
      $Galileo = $arr["Galileo"];
      $SatelliteBasedAugmentationSystem = $arr["SatelliteBasedAugmentationSystem"];
      $NavyNavigationSatelliteSystemNnss = $arr["NavyNavigationSatelliteSystemNnss"];
      $RussianLeoNavigation = $arr["RussianLeoNavigation"];
      $SpaceAndEarthScience = $arr["SpaceAndEarthScience"];
      $Geodetic = $arr["Geodetic"];
      $Engineering = $arr["Engineering"];
      $Education = $arr["Education"];
      $MiscellaneousMilitary = $arr["MiscellaneousMilitary"];
      $RadarCalibration = $arr["RadarCalibration"];
      $Cubesats = $arr["Cubesats"];
      $MiscellaneousSatellitesOther = $arr["MiscellaneousSatellitesOther"];
      $Fengyun1CDebris = $arr["Fengyun1CDebris"];
      $Iridium33Debris = $arr["Iridium33Debris"];
      $Cosmos2251Debris = $arr["Cosmos2251Debris"];
      $BreezeMRBBreakup = $arr["BreezeMRBBreakup"];


  $a3=array($Last30Days,$SpaceStations,$HundredOrSoBrightest,$Weather,$Noaa,$Goes,$EarthResources,$SearchAndRescueSarsat,$DisasterMonitoring,$TrackingAndDataRelaySatelliteSystemTdrss,$Geostationary,$Intelsat,$Gorizont,$Raduga,$Molniya,$Iridium,$Orbcomm,$Globalstar,$AmateurRadio,$Experimental,$CommunicationSatellitesOther,$GpsOperational,$GlonassOperational,$Galileo,$SatelliteBasedAugmentationSystem,$NavyNavigationSatelliteSystemNnss,$RussianLeoNavigation,$SpaceAndEarthScience,$Geodetic,$Engineering,$Education,$MiscellaneousMilitary,$RadarCalibration,$Cubesats,$MiscellaneousSatellitesOther,$Fengyun1CDebris,$Iridium33Debris,$Cosmos2251Debris,$BreezeMRBBreakup);
  $a4=array("Last30Days","SpaceStations","HundredOrSoBrightest","Weather","Noaa","Goes","EarthResources","SearchAndRescueSarsat","DisasterMonitoring","TrackingAndDataRelaySatelliteSystemTdrss","Geostationary","Intelsat","Gorizont","Raduga","Molniya","Iridium","Orbcomm","Globalstar","AmateurRadio","Experimental","CommunicationSatellitesOther","GpsOperational","GlonassOperational","Galileo","SatelliteBasedAugmentationSystem","NavyNavigationSatelliteSystemNnss","RussianLeoNavigation","SpaceAndEarthScience","Geodetic","Engineering","Education","MiscellaneousMilitary","RadarCalibration","Cubesats","MiscellaneousSatellitesOther","Fengyun1CDebris","Iridium33Debris","Cosmos2251Debris","BreezeMRBBreakup");
  $arr=array_combine($a3, $a4);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM $arr[$constellation] order by mission ASC";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

?>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="pulldownGroup2" name="pulldownGroup" method="post" >   

  <table class="pulldown">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p class="pulldownheader">Satellite Results (Norad Number and Satellite Name)</p>
        <select id="satellite" name="satellite" value=$satellite >
      <option class="subdued" value=$satellite>Select for Satellite or leave blank for Constellation</option>
<?php
      $i = 0;   
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
            // Display the satellite data
              if ($i == 0) {
                echo '<option value=$satellite>' . $row['mission'] . ' ' . $row['satellite'] . '</option>';
              }
            }
?>
        <input id="submit" type=submit value=submit />
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<?php
    //while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
?>

  <table class="chosensat">
    <tr>
      <td class="sat2">Satellite Mission and Name: <?php $row['mission'] . ' ' . $row['satellite']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sat2">Epoch Time and Greenwich time: <?php $row['epochTime'] . ' ' . $row['gmtTime']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sat2">Inclination: <?php $row['inclination']; ?> deg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sat2">Right Ascension: <?php $row['raan']; ?> deg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sat2">Eccentricity: <?php $row['eccentricity']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sat2">Argument of Perigee: <?php $row['argOfPerigee']; ?> deg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sat2">Mean Anomaly: <?php $row['meanAnomaly']; ?> deg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sat2">Mean Motion: <?php $row['meanMotion']; ?> rev/day</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<?php
    //}
?>

  </form>

<p class="pulldownheader2">Selected Constellation:


<?php

  if($constellation=="Last 30 Days") echo $Last30Days;
    elseif($constellation=="Space Stations") echo $SpaceStations;
    elseif($constellation=="Hundred Or So Brightest") echo $HundredOrSoBrightest;
    elseif($constellation=="Weather") echo $Weather;
    elseif($constellation=="Noaa") echo $Noaa;
    elseif($constellation=="Goes") echo $Goes;
    elseif($constellation=="Earth Resources") echo $EarthResources;
    elseif($constellation=="Search And Rescue (Sarsat)") echo $SearchAndRescueSarsat;
    elseif($constellation=="Disaster Monitoring") echo $DisasterMonitoring;
    elseif($constellation=="Tracking And Data Relay Satellite System (Tdrss)") echo $TrackingAndDataRelaySatelliteSystemTdrss;
    elseif($constellation=="Geostationary") echo $Geostationary;
    elseif($constellation=="Intelsat") echo $Intelsat;
    elseif($constellation=="Gorizont") echo $Gorizont;
    elseif($constellation=="Raduga") echo $Raduga;
    elseif($constellation=="Molniya") echo $Molniya;
    elseif($constellation=="Iridium") echo $Iridium;
    elseif($constellation=="Orbcomm") echo $Orbcomm;
    elseif($constellation=="Globalstar") echo $Globalstar;
    elseif($constellation=="Amateur Radio") echo $AmateurRadio;
    elseif($constellation=="Experimental") echo $Experimental;
    elseif($constellation=="Communication Satellites - Other") echo $CommunicationSatellitesOther;
    elseif($constellation=="Gps Operational") echo $GpsOperational;
    elseif($constellation=="Glonass Operational") echo $GlonassOperational;
    elseif($constellation=="Galileo") echo $Galileo;
    elseif($constellation=="Satellite-Based Augmentation System") echo $SatelliteBasedAugmentationSystem;
    elseif($constellation=="Navy Navigation Satellite System (Nnss)") echo $NavyNavigationSatelliteSystemNnss;
    elseif($constellation=="Russian Leo Navigation") echo $RussianLeoNavigation;
    elseif($constellation=="Space And Earth Science") echo $SpaceAndEarthScience;
    elseif($constellation=="Geodetic") echo $Geodetic;
    elseif($constellation=="Engineering") echo $Engineering;
    elseif($constellation=="Education") echo $Education;
    elseif($constellation=="Miscellaneous Military") echo $MiscellaneousMilitary;
    elseif($constellation=="Radar Calibration") echo $RadarCalibration;
    elseif($constellation=="Cubesats") echo $Cubesats;
    elseif($constellation=="Miscellaneous Satellites - Other") echo $MiscellaneousSatellitesOther;
    elseif($constellation=="Fengyun 1C Debris") echo $Fengyun1CDebris;
    elseif($constellation=="Iridium 33 Debris") echo $Iridium33Debris;
    elseif($constellation=="Cosmos 2251 Debris") echo $Cosmos2251Debris;
    elseif($constellation=="Breeze Breakup") echo $BreezeMRBBreakup;
    else echo $constellation;

?> 

</p>

</div>


<div id="map3d"></div>


<?php

  // Retrieve the data from MySQL
  $query2 = "SELECT * FROM $arr[$constellation] ORDER BY id ASC";
  $data2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);


  // Loop through the array of data, formatting it as HTML 
  echo '<table class="tablecontent">';

    echo '<tr><td colspan="11" class="constellationheader">' . $constellation . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><th width="20px" class="headerinfo"><strong>ID:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th width="180px" class="headerinfo"><strong>Satellite:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th class="headerinfo"><strong>Mission:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th class="headerinfo"><strong>Epoch Time:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th width="160px" class="headerinfo"><strong>GMT:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th class="headerinfo"><strong>Inclination:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th class="headerinfo"><strong>RAAN:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th class="headerinfo"><strong>Eccentricity:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th width="120px" class="headerinfo"><strong>Argument of Perigee:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th class="headerinfo"><strong>Mean Anomaly:</strong></th>';
    echo '<th class="headerinfo"><strong>Mean Motion:</strong></th></tr>';

  $i = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data2)) { 
    // Display the satellite data
    if ($i == 0) {

    echo '<tr><td align="center" width="20px" class="sat">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="180px" class="sat">' . $row['satellite'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="sat">' . $row['mission'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="sat">' . $row['epochTime'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="160px" class="sat">' . $row['gmtTime'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="sat">' . $row['inclination'] . ' deg' . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="sat">' . $row['raan'] . ' deg' . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="sat">' . $row['eccentricity'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="120px" class="sat">' . $row['argOfPerigee'] . ' deg' . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="sat">' . $row['meanAnomaly'] . ' deg' . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="sat">' . $row['meanMotion'] . ' rev/day' . '</td></tr>';

    }

  }

  echo '</table>';

  mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not very experienced with all of this but I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little hard to read, and you'd get a lot of benefits ad clarity from using arrays to keep track of all of your variables.

For instance, in your "constellation query" dropdown, you can use something like the following:

```
$constellations = array('Last 30 Days', 'Space Stations', 'etc..');
foreach ($constellations as $constellation) {
   $selected = null;
   if ($_POST['constellation'] == $constellation) {
     $selected = ' selected';
   }
   echo "<option value=\"$constellation\" $selected>$constellation</option>";
}
```

As for your actually question. I noticed you have a "/form" tag inside of your "select" (id="constellation"). I personally prefer to put the "form" tags outside of the "table". My guess is if you're able to clean up the code with some arrays you might find other small errors like this that prevent your forms from working. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I was experimenting with the <form> tag to see if anything would change if I enclosed both tables within the form. It doesn't really make any sense but I didn't receive any errors so I kept it that way for the time being. I'll set it right. As far as the arrays go I managed to get the first query to work with it as is but I'll look at other options to improve the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure, maybe you can try cleaning the code and re-posting if it's still not working. At least then it might be easier for everybody to see a problem.